# How to use Regex to see if String matches another string partially (or completely)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a trivia system, and the variable `triviaA` is changed to the updated Answer every time there is a new question. I was wondering how I could use Regex to make it so that if `triviaA = 'eagle'` then if someone submitted the answer as `eagle` but with a small spelling mistake, the if statement would still return both the `triviaA` answer and the players answer return true.

I'm new to Regex, please excuse my mistakes.

Comment: so if someone writes `ewgle` it should find `eagle`, right?

Comment: What would you define a small spelling mistake: same letters but different word, one or two extra letters?

Comment: yes! like only 1 misspelled letter allowed. @georg

Comment: I believe you are looking to do fuzzy matching. This involves calculating similarity scores and the like, so I would probably recommend using a library e.g. Fuse.js or fuzzyset.js

Comment: This is not a really regex problem, it's a soundex one.  Have a look here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Comment: @whiterabbitj i think both, 1 misspelled letter or 1 extra letter would be allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically build a regular expression that matches all possible "errors" (wrong/missing/extra letter) and apply it to the source:

```js
function fuzzyContains(word, str) {
    let r = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        // wrong letter
        r.push(word.slice(0, i) + '[a-z]' + word.slice(i + 1));
        // missing letter
        r.push(word.slice(0, i) + '' + word.slice(i + 1));
        // extra letter
        r.push(word.slice(0, i) + '[a-z]' + word.slice(i));
    }
    return new RegExp(r.join('|')).test(str)
}


console.log(fuzzyContains('eagle', 'fly, ewgle, fly'))
console.log(fuzzyContains('eagle', 'fly, eagl, fly'))
console.log(fuzzyContains('eagle', 'fly, eaggle, fly'))
console.log(fuzzyContains('eagle', 'fly, eagly, fly'))
```

See https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html for other interesting ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This would actually be quite difficult to do with RegEx. However, there's a concept in computing called "edit distance", which is a measure of how "similar" two strings are, and there are known algorithms to calculate that. Which means there are Node packages to calculate it :)

For instance, there's the aptly named Node package `edit-distance`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-distance (Note: edit distance is sometimes called Levenshtein edit distance, named after the man who first studied it.)

I'll give you an example using that package; other packages may work somewhat differently to calculate the same thing.

There are three types of changes between two strings: an insertion, where a character is added in one that's not in the other; a deletion, where a character is removed in one that's there in the other; and an update/substitution, where a letter is changed between the strings. Using the edit-distance package, you define a function that assigns a cost to each of these types of changes. Then you call the package's levenshtein method, passing it the two strings and the three functions, and it returns an object with a `distance` property that is the sum score.

Assuming your cost functions return non-negative values, a score of 0 means the two strings are identical, and higher numbers mean they're more different. So you can use this to compare the entered value with the correct string and, if the result is lower than a certain threshold, accept it as "correct excluding typos".